# duplicate records in SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am getting multiple results in my SQL query. I have three tables: payments, credits, and charges. At the end of each month I need to have a balance forward based on the account holder (let's call said person owner) I have tried different queries but keep getting duplicate rows. I know it has to do with my `WHERE` clause but I don't know how to fix it.

In my test data I have one record for `payments`:

`owner`: 1001
`date`:2014-03-23
`amount`:50.00

I get 3 of that record returned from the query:

```
SELECT p.amount
FROM payments p, charges ch, credits cr
WHERE (p.owner = 1001 AND ch.owner = 1001 AND cr.owner = 1001)
```

I know that isn't right, but I do not know the proper way to query it. I want just the one row returned. Eventually I will use a `SUM()` on the `amount` from each table and add a dates to the `WHERE` clause.

First, though, I need to get this resolved. Thanks for any help.

---

EDIT: I have made a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0c4d/1/0) of the tables. The names are less generic. I am actually using `unit`, not `owner`. Though it really wouldn't matter.

Comment: This looks like it's due to the fact that you don't actually have any condition joining these three tables, and are instead getting a cartesian product from them (does one of them have 3 rows?). Please post a little more about the structure of all 3 tables and a small sample rowset from each, though we could probably guess at what you're doing by extrapolating from what you already tried.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added a fiddle to my post

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT p.amount
FROM payments p, charges ch, credits cr
WHERE (p.owner = 1001 AND ch.owner = 1001 AND cr.owner = 1001 AND p.owner=ch.owner AND
p.owner=cr.owner
)
```

Comment: Can you give me field of tables?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It came back: `amount <break>
50.00 <break>
50.00 <break>
50.00 <break>
`

Comment: i want to know structure of tables

Comment: i will give 390 amount to forward. What is problem now?

Comment: If you look at the tables that amount is not correct. There is a total of $190 if absolute value is used. Some values are negative, and rightly so. The real balance fwd should be $10 I believe.

Comment: From which table you want amount. i think unit_charges am i right?

Comment: I want a balance forward. That means I would need to have an equation like this: balance fwd = (payments+credits)+(charges)  Charges is already a negative value in the database otherwise i would have to subtract it.

Comment: Try this one

select (p.amount+cr.amount+sum(ch.amount)) AS "Forward Amount" from 
unit_payments p,
unit_credits cr,
unit_charges ch
WHERE
p.unit = 1001 AND ch.unit = 1001 AND cr.unit = 1001 AND 
cr.unit=p.unit AND
cr.unit=ch.unit AND
p.unit=ch.unit

Answer (score 0):

You can limit it with

SELECT p.amount
FROM payments p, charges ch, credits cr
WHERE (p.owner = 1001 AND ch.owner = 1001 AND cr.owner = 1001)
LIMIT 1

or in any case, one of those three tables has three record for owner 1001 that's why it's displaying three. It's better if you can give the data of 1001 from these three tables so we can see

Comment: What is the balance FWD you are expecting?