# Unknown column in field list in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I [posted a question regarding this issue yesterday with no luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799907/duplicate-records-in-sql-join) Today I thought I had finally figured it out. However, I get an error `Unknown column 'amount' in 'field list'`

What I am trying to do is get a **Balance Fwd**. I want to add up all the `payments` for a month, all the `charges` for a month, and all the `credits` for a month and then `SUM()` them all to give me a balance forward for the next month. the equation would be:

balance forward = (SUM(payments) + SUM(charges)) - SUM(credits)

Here is the last query I came up with:

```
SELECT p.Pamount+ch.CHamount-cr.CRamount AS BalanceFwd FROM
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS Pamount      FROM payments       WHERE unit = 1001 AND date < '2014-04-01') p,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS CHamount     FROM unit_charges   WHERE unit = 1001 AND charged_dtm < '2014-04-01') ch,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS CRamount     FROM unit_credits   WHERE unit = 1001 AND issued < '2014-04-01') cr
```

I have made a [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0c4d/1/0) if you're interested in seeing my problem in more context.

Comment: A stupid question: There is the column amount in your table?

Comment: Yes, in all of them. You can see for yourself in the fiddle

Comment: The fiddle also runs fine. Are you *sure* they're in your tables? Sometimes you're running queries on a database with a different schema by accident.

Comment: Yes. I exported the `CREATE` statements from my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found 2 problems with your query:

- Payment table name should be `unit_payments`
- If subquery doesn't return result then total result is `null`. So I've added [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Here my variant:

```
SELECT coalesce(p.Pamount,0)+coalesce(ch.CHamount,0)-coalesce(cr.CRamount,0) AS BalanceFwd FROM
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS Pamount      FROM unit_payments  WHERE unit = 1001 AND date < '2014-04-01') p,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS CHamount     FROM unit_charges   WHERE unit = 1001 AND charged_dtm < '2014-04-01') ch,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS CRamount     FROM unit_credits   WHERE unit = 1001 AND issued < '2014-04-01') cr
```

Comment: Thank you. I spotted my table name mistake as well. I didn't catch it previously because of the nature of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
    SELECT p.Pamount+ch.CHamount-cr.CRamount AS BalanceFwd FROM
    (SELECT SUM(a.amount) AS Pamount      FROM payments a      WHERE a.unit = 1001 AND a.date < '2014-04-01') p,
    (SELECT SUM(b.amount) AS CHamount     FROM unit_charges b  WHERE b.unit = 1001 AND b.charged_dtm < '2014-04-01') ch,
    (SELECT SUM(c.amount) AS CRamount     FROM unit_credits c  WHERE c.unit = 1001 AND c.issued < '2014-04-01') cr
```

Comment: I got the following error: `Unknown column 'a.amount' in 'field list'`

Comment: Have you sure that the table payments have the column amount?

Comment: you forgot to put `unit_` before `payments`. I fixed that and it returned `NULL`

Comment: In the sql fiddle this table not exists.

Comment: because he misspelled it

Comment: I HAD IT MISSPELLED! omg